# Initializing Bigtable with test data

Tags: google-app-engine, bigtable

My app has a Google App engine back end which uses BigTable for it's persistence.  I have some functional tests I want to run which are dependent on existing Test data being preloaded in the database.  What is the best way to preload this data as I want each test to start from a known state.  Currently each test cleans down the database and calls a function which loads test data but this will not scale well as I intend to have 100s of tests and eventually lots of test data that these tests will depend on.

Answer (score 0):

Through the admin console, you can [backup and restore datastores](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin#Backup_And_Restore) - even from one app to another.  You could have a backup of the tests' initial state that you restored any time you wanted to go through testing.

Comment: Thanks but it's not really what I'm looking for. I want to run numerous tests but prior to running each test I want to programatically restore the database to a known state. If I was using a Relational database I could just clear each table and write  a block of SQL to do the job but I don't seem to be able to do a similar approach with Big Table.